# Listen for certain IP address and port with tcplistener

Tags: c#, tcp, nat-traversal

I'm creating a screen sharing application. To allow for nat traversal I'm having to do this through a server, I'm just wondering how I can check that the client trying to connect to the server is the one I want to connect and not someone else, whilst not actually blocking other people from being able to connect to that port.

I'm thinking of using BeginAcceptTcpClient() instead of AcceptTcpClient() is there a way to check who is trying to connect before it accepts the connection this way so it can be picked up by the TcpListener later?

The only other thing I can of is to send the ID of the person I want to send the image to in the connection and let the server handle who to send it to but would that be too slow or resource intensive?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should take a look on how [join.me](https://www.join.me) makes it:

- On first machine start the Observable.

  - This connects to the central server and receives a unique id (ticket) that will be shown to the user.
- On the second machine start the Observer.

  - This connects also to the central server and awaits an entering of the desired id to connect to.
- Now the user on the observable machine has to communicate the id to the observer guy through a different channel (e.g. phone).
- On the observer the ticket number is entered and the server can send both machines the ip address and port of each other where their did the hole punching. If a direct connect is possible, the central server has finished its work, otherwise both sides will send their data to the server and from their to the other client.

So to ensure that the correct clients are connected simply create a unique id which both sides have to share through a different communication channel.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following should be enough to see if the correct client has connected to your server:

1. Create a TCPListener and start accepting connections either synchronously or async. I'm using the synchronous example from MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.accepttcpclient(v=vs.110).aspx
2. When a client connects, create a stream to read data sent by the client like this:

   NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
   i = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
3. Deserialize the message from bytes to string and check if it, for example, matches a unique ID that you are expecting:

`

```
data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, i);
//There are, of course, better ways of doing this.
if(data.Equals("HandshakeId")
{
//start receiving/sending data in a loop
}
else
{
 // Shutdown and end connection
  client.Close();
}
```

`

A more interesting question is how to capture the actual screen you'll be sharing. I personally have done this in VS C++, and the performance was okay. There are several ways to do it, i.e. using GDI+, using DirectX or OpenGL, the list goes on..

I'm curious as to what are you planing to use :)